# Can't load develop for windows option in android studio with flutter

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

[I have downloaded the newest sdk of flutter, (2.10) and connected it to android studio.
However, when creating a new flutter project android studio doesn't offer me the develop for windows option as a clickable option.
What do?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAZ8W.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi there you need to add the config to flutter using the following command(s) from your terminal.

```
flutter config --enable-windows-desktop
flutter config --enable-linux-desktop
flutter config --enable-macos-desktop
```

Once you have done this restart Android Studio.

https://docs.flutter.dev/desktop

Comment: Hi, I enable windows desktop in config, but Android Studio (latest version 2021.1.1 Patch 1) has Windows platform disabled. Same problem is in latest Idea community IDE. Visual Studio is installed (community 2019 version 16.11.32126.315). Flutter doctor say all is ok. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: You might find that the Variable its setting is not being found by Android Studio, do you maybe have two versions installed or have recently changed something. I know you have Visual Studio installed, but did you install the C-development library as well.